# Linux umount a device from a script running in the device itself

Tags: linux, bash, shell, umount

I've a mounted iso image in the path:

```
/mnt/iso
```

Inside this iso I've an install script install.sh
I run the installation script from the iso and at the end the script ask to the user if he want to umount the iso itself. 
If the user press "y" the script execute the following code:

```
cd /
umount /mnt/iso
echo "Installation completed!"
```

Unfortunately when the script tries to execute the umount there's an error

```
umount: /mnt/iso: device is busy
```

I suppose it's due to the fact that the virtual device is busy from the script itself.
How can make it work?
Tnx

Comment: Do you run install.sh from inside `/mnt/iso`? What if you try running it from outside? My hypothesis is that the the problem is not the install script (because it does `cd /`) but is that the calling shell is inside `/mnt/iso`.

Comment: There must be some files being used. Check it with `lsof`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-l` or `--lazy` switch to `umount` which will do a lazy umount, where it is only fully unmounted once it is no longer in use. The full description in the manual page (this is a linux specific option) is:

> Lazy unmount.  Detach the filesystem from the filesystem hierarchy
>   now, and cleanup all references to the filesystem as soon as it is not
>   busy anymore.  (Requires kernel 2.4.11 or later.)

Comment: Hi, there's a problem that I noticed only now. When I use the lazy umount the iso is correctly unmounted but if I try to execute losetup -a I see that the loop devices remain. 
/dev/loop0: [0801]:773311 (/myIso.iso)
/dev/loop1: [0801]:773311 (/myIso.iso)
/dev/loop2: [0801]:773311 (/myIso.iso)
/dev/loop3: [0801]:769575 (/myIso.iso)

How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

TomH's solution will resolve the issue if you are using the latest.  Otherwise the comment by Simone Palazzo is your best bet.  You are unmounting something through a script located in the area you are unmounting.  If you run the script from the root directory it will be successful.